# Retro mecha-esque anime where a girl visits a garage, and exits it in a red mech/vehicle hybrid

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I can’t remember much of it, as I only saw a clip of it from YouTube a long time ago, but it looked different from most other mecha anime. It seemed to be an older anime.

In the scene, there was this girl who entered a garage; a guy in the garage offered to let her enter this mech/vehicle hybrid. It had two wheels/legs and was red in nature. It quickly took her out of the garage and sped her down the street; I believe it was jumping and the like.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of the landmates in Appleseed (as far there is a garage with with a guy mechanic who introduces the female protagonist to the vehicle), but they were not red and not on wheels (however they fought some enemy mechs on wheels).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like it could be [Rideback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rideback_(manga)#Anime), where the mechs are transformable motorcycles.

Plot synopsis from Wikipedia:

> In the year of 2025, an organization called the GGP has taken control of the world. Rin Ogata was a promising up-and-coming ballet dancer, but suffered a serious injury while dancing and decided to quit. Years later in college, she comes across a club building and soon finds herself intrigued by a transforming motorcycle-like robotic vehicle called a "Rideback". She soon finds that her unique ballet skills with balance and finesse make her a born natural on a Rideback. However, those same skills also get her into serious trouble with the government.

Comment: You can see a red motorbike at 0:30 in the trailer.

Comment: Rideback was precisely it, thank you.

Comment: FYI .. the video link is no longer live